# Perl command meaning with -d

Tags: perl

I found this program and I can't figure out what this `if` statement is

```
if(!(-d "$string_value"))
```

The `string_value` may have `/default/main/folder1`.

Answer (score 1):

That looks very much like perl syntax, given the parentheses. If so, (-d $string_value) checks to see if $string_value is a directory. The if statement executes if $string_value is ! (not) a directory.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is valid. The `-d` operator is testing whether a path string is a directory in Bash or in Perl, but I'm not aware of file operators in Groovy. This looks like [Perl code](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html).

Answer (score 0):

From perldoc

> > [-d](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html)   Check whether File is a directory.
> >
> > [!](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Symbolic-Unary-Operators)  It is Symbolic Unary Operators. It is performs logical negation, that is, "not".

If `$string_value` is a directory it will give the result for `-d $string_value` is true(`1`). But you are checking whether satisfying condition should be false. it means `!1` so if it is not a directory block will be execute.

It can be written as `unless(-d $string_value)`

Comment: The issue is that the statement is returning different values(true/false) for the same $string_value and I can't figure out why that is.  What are criteria for making it a directory?  If there are spaces maybe before or after can cause an issue?

Comment: or maybe the length is too long or special characters in the $string_value?

Comment: I'm not sure about string length is too long. But your string having special character use the `quotemeta`  to escape all special character